# If button not pressed after x amount of seconds, do something

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsmutablearray, slideshow, nstimer

I have a simple slideshow app which displays images at 5 second intervals. The image can be rated on a scale of 1-5 by pressing a button, with the rating getting stored in a `NSMutableArray` (called "rated"). At the minute, each button gets stored in the array using a `switch` statement.

```
- (IBAction)setRating:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    int bTag = button.tag;
    rating = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", bTag];
    _ratingChoice.text = rating;

    // Determine which button was pressed, add to array
    switch (button.tag) 
    {
        case 1:
            [self.rated addObject:rating];
            NSLog(@"Rating 1 button pressed");
            break;

        ...

        case 5:
            [self.rated addObject:rating];
            NSLog(@"Rating 5 button pressed");
            break;
    }
```

I need to somehow insert a "Null" value into the array if no button is clicked after 5 seconds, before the next image displays. 
    I have tried to use `NSTimer` but can't seem to figure it out. I had included the code below in the button method, but it didn't do anything. 
    (I was testing it by not pressing any button, in the hope that "Null" would be added to the array after 5 seconds). 
    I have declared `NSTimer *clickTime;` in the header file.

```
    _clickTime = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self 

    selector:@selector(ratingClicked:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


-(void)ratingClicked:(NSTimer*)clickTime
{
    [self.rated addObject:@"Null"];
    NSLog(@"Null added to array");
    NSLog(@"%@", self.rated);
}
```

Another issue is that any button can be pressed multiple times on each image, causing more values to be added to the array. I need to somehow limit one button click to each image.

Should I somehow implement method which allows one button click per 5 seconds?

Would I need to change my array to `addObject:atIndex:` as a solution to both of my questions? Thanks!

Comment: use perform selector after delay

Comment: Thanks, this does work, though only partially solves my problem. It only adds a "Null" value if a button has been pressed initially. If no button is ever pressed, no value is added. I need a "Null" value to be added every 5 seconds unless a button is pressed from when the slideshow starts. I have added the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` in the `setRating` (button clicked) method, is this the the correct place to put it?

Comment: `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` should be added **when the image is first displayed** and not when the button is pressed. By calling `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` when the image is displayed, you are asking the program to add a 'null' value after 5 seconds. If a rating button is pressed, you can cancel the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` request by using `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object` method. This cancellation should be done before the next image is shown for rating. This solution provides more clarity than 'addObject:atIndex:'.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I have added it to my `startSlideShow` method and it is now working. My only issue now is that once a button has been pressed, it stops inserting "Null". I need to make it insert "Null" into the array every 5 seconds unless a button is pressed. So if I rate image numbers 1 & 4, then images 2 & 3 should have "Null". Does that make sense? Apologies for not making this clear originally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this i was able to do different action on button tapped or not:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
  [self setTimer];
}

  //--> set your timer
  -(void)setTimer
 {
    self.mTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self 
    selector:@selector(btnNotPushed) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
 }

  -(void)btnNotPushed
  {
    //--> do your stuff on button not clicked
    [self resetTimer];
    [self setTimer];
  }
   -(void)resetTimer
    {
     [ self.mTimer invalidate];
     self.mTimer = nil;
    }

   //--> your method on button tap;
   -(IBAction)pushClicked:(id)sender
   {
     [self resetTimer];
     [self setTimer];
    //-->do your stuff on button clicked;
   }
```

You will be able to perform your functionality implementing the above as per your code.

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much exactly the functionality I was looking for! My only problem now is the timer never stops, it keeps adding a "Null" value to the array every 5 seconds. Is there something I should do to stop the timer? Once my slideshow is over, a `UIAlertView` pops up to tell the user, and goes back to the `MainUIViewController.xib`. I have tried to set the `resetTimer` when the user dismisses the popup but it still runs. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the double post, I managed to get the timer to stop by adding `resetTimer` to the `UIAlertView`, so once the user dismisses it, the timer resets and doesn't start until the slideshow starts again.The issue now is that a "Null" value gets added to the array every time the app starts, regardless if a button is pressed. The "Null" value should only get added if no button has been pressed at all after 5 seconds after the slideshow starts. Can you help? I can stop this by removing `setTimer` in the `viewDidLoad` method, but then no "Null" gets added until a button is pressed.

Comment: You must be adding Null at the wrong method add your Null to array when the desired condition is true it all depends on your logic, rest above code answers your question, please make another thread to ask different question.

Comment: Ok I'll have another look when I'm home, I'm sure you're right, it's probably something I just need to adjust. Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code immediately after displaying the image:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(ratingClicked:)
           afterDelay:5.0];
```

I would also suggest changing the name of your `ratingClicked:` method to `ratingNotClicked`:

```
-(void)ratingNotClicked{
    [self.rated addObject:@"Null"];
    NSLog(@"Null added to array");
    NSLog(@"%@", self.rated);
}
```

By calling performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: when the image is displayed, you are asking the program to add a 'null' value after 5 seconds.

If one of the rating buttons have been pressed, you can cancel the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` request by using cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: method:

```
- (IBAction)setRating:(id)sender {
[self cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                     selector:@selector(ratingClicked:)];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    int bTag = button.tag;
    rating = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", bTag];
    _ratingChoice.text = rating;

    // Determine which button was pressed, add to array
switch (button.tag) {
    case 1:
        [self.rated addObject:rating];
        NSLog(@"Rating 1 button pressed");
        break;

    ...

    case 5:
        [self.rated addObject:rating];
        NSLog(@"Rating 5 button pressed");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for suggestion, usage of [such control](https://github.com/dyang/DYRateView) instead of button clicks will give better user experience and it is easy to manage too.

Comment: That looks nice, it's something I will have a look at, thanks!